# How to Interpret Exterior Derivative as Infinitesimal

Tags: differential-forms, infinitesimals

In Riemann Integral, one can intuitively interpret $dx$ as infinitesimal, and it makes sense, but in differential forms, it lost this interpretation, is there a way to make connection between these two?

The $d$ in $dx$ as infinitesimal can roughly be interpreted as a function ($\Delta f \approx f'(x)\Delta x$). So what I'm asking is another direction, namely, Is there a way to interpret ($dx$ as 1-form) as ($dx$ as infinitesimal)?

Based on my very limited knowledge, I think the differential form stuff is an axiomatic system, right? You defined some rules, and you play with it. So you can interpret any way you want, as long as it makes sense, (because it's just symbols).

Comment: there was recently an MSE Blog article written on exactly this. Perhaps someone wiser than I can provide a link.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Any keywords so I can search it?

Comment: Here is is: http://math.blogoverflow.com/ there must be some easy way to find it, but it escapes me...

Comment: Not realy what you are searching, but terrific: http://www.math.boun.edu.tr/instructors/ozturk/eskiders/fall04math488/bachman.pdf.

Comment: Not sure whether it's exactly what you want, but he does talk about differential $1$-forms... http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/11/03/more-than-infinitesimal-what-is-dx/?cb=1